# SSH to a remote Machine using a different Local ID

Tags: ssh, scp

I am logged in as "user1".

```
Host A:
  user1
  user2

Host B:
  remoteuser.
```

There is a trust relationship setup between `user2` on `Host A` and `remoteuser` on `Host B`.

However the scripts are executed by `user1` on `Host A`.

How can I utilize already established trust relationship of `user2` in the script that is being executed by `user1` on `Host A`.

I do not want to establish a trust relationship between `user1` and `remotehost`.

Comment: What do you mean by a "trust relationship"?  Do you mean a shared ssh key, or that user2 has already authenticated and has a current session?  Can user1 use `sudo` to become user2 for some commands?

Comment: Trust relationship - Well, `user2` can login to `Host B` without a password. Public keys are added in `authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy user2's private key to user1:

```
cp /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa     /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.user2
cp /home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.user2.pub
chown user1:group1 /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.user2{,.pub}
```

As user1, connect with this alternate identity:

```
ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.user2
```

Or add host entry to /home/user1/.ssh/config

```
Host B
  IdentityFile /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.user2
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. This worked!!! However only with RSA Key pair and not with DSA Key pai

Answer (score 0):

"Trust of relationship" is unknow in unix world. We know of `sudo` or `ssh` without password.

You could not easily have a three step "trust" (user1@A -> user2@A -> remoteuser@B).

either

1. transfert script to user2
2. allow user1 to passwordless sudo to user2
3. allow user1 to passwordless log to B as remoteuser

You will have to edit `/etc/sudoers.conf` or copy user2 private key to user1's ones.

Comment: “Trust relationship” is a generic term that covers things like one account having an SSH key that lets it log into another account, or a sudoer entry, etc. You may not know the term, but the concept is certainly known.